# flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

what possibly i am doing wrong or what i can do with this code that help me to render requested page in same window instead of new one every time i hit button which i have created using actionscript 3.0 .
code is

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var get_page:URLRequest = new URLRequest("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/lifeline/healthtips.html");

tips_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tipsClick);

function tipsClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
navigateToURL(get_page);

 }
```

Comment: What happens when you try and use this code? An explicit error? Or just nothing? Or...?

Comment: it just simply displaying requested page in new window.every time i hit button.why i dont know ,no error no nothing.

Comment: @John Drummond has your answer. I would just like to add that it might be better to use relative paths rather than absolute paths in your url. E.g. if your swf file is in the same folder as the other html files(lifeline folder), you could just use 

var get_page:URLRequest = new URLRequest("healthtips.html");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `navigateToURL(get_page, "_self")`

See: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html